# Adding extra information in user object in passport.js or somewhere in session

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I want to add custom keys in the user object that is coming from mongodb and that is going to be used by passport.js but i wonder why i can't add more keys to that object, here is my code.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        Users.model(false).findOne( {email:username,password:encodePassword(password) }, function(err, user) {
            if( err ){ // validation failed
                console.log('Error Occurred');
                return done(err);
            }
            else if(user != null){

                user['customKey'] = "customValue"; // it is not setting

                console.log(user);

                return done(null, user);
            }
            else {

                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
        });
    }
));
///Session handling
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    Users.model(false).findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Comment: I got my answer by performing some debugging. The thing is, when mongoose return a document it is not as simple as just like a json object, it has some properties set by mongoose.js or perhaps by the mongodb itself. So the custom key successfully adds to that object (You can check by)

    console.log(Object.keys(user));

but it is not at the correct place, from where mongoose.js show the properties of the schema.

Comment: Can you post your answer with the code please ^_^

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue with sequelize. I can delete properties (like password) but can't add properties. EDIT: Turns out user.dataValues.hi = 'hi'; works with sequelize. May be different for other ORMs. Never seen behavior like this before. How can user.password = undefined work but user.hi = 'hi' doesn't? It doesn't even technically have a .password field, it's the .dataValues.password field which is deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23524426/639579):

> Either in the deserialization function, before returning the user
>
> ```
> passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
>     getUser(id).then(function(user) {
>         user.whatever = 'you like';
>         return done(null, user);
>     });
> });
> ```
>
> or in an express middleware (before the router).
>
> ```
> app.use(function(req, res, next) {
>     if(req.user) req.user.whatever = 'you like';
>     next();
> });
> ```

Comment: I recommend the middleware route, I use such a function to add last visit date-time to the req.session, and am also developing middleware in using app.all('*') to do IP request tracking

Comment: Is it appropriate to use it in the serialization function?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multi provider login and want dynamic value add to user object.

```
var customKey = null;

//Store user id in session
passport.deserializeUser(function (Id, done) {

    User.findById(Id, function (err, user) {

        var newUser = user.toObject();
        newUser['customKey'] = customKey;

        done(err, newUser);
    });
});

//Local login
passport.use('local.login', new LocalStrategy({
....
customKey = "isLocal";
....

// Facebook login
passport.use('facebook.login', new LocalStrategy({
....
customKey = "isFacebook";
....
```

Access in Router:

```
req.user.customKey;
```

Use in template:

```
// in app.js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});

//In hbs template:
{{user.customKey}}
```

Hope to help you.