# PassportJS adding another property to req.user

Tags: node.js, passport.js

How would I add a variable to the request.user property?

Most of my routes involve checking for the authenticated user via "req.userusername".

How could I add another field for location. I ask this because I want to add a location field. to the req.user object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either in the deserialization function, before returning the user

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    getUser(id).then(function(user) {
        user.whatever = 'you like';
        return done(null, user);
    });
});
```

or in an express middleware (before the router).

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user) req.user.whatever = 'you like';
    next();
});
```

Comment: Is it ok to use it in the serialization function?

Comment: @Nima The main purpose of this (OP's question) approach is to make some additional data available in your route handlers or middlewares that come after deserializing the data from the database. Serialization OTOH is probably the last thing that's done on a route, no? Like there probably won't be any more routes or middlewares where you could use the added property (`req.user.whatever`). If there are, by all means use it.