# How is getCompany defined on req.user in passportjs?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I was just going through a model code HERE. and i see certain the following in a route file (line of code can be found [**HERE**](https://github.com/timeoff-management/timeoff-management-application/blob/master/lib/route/departments.js#L92)) :

```
router.get('/departments/', function(req, res){
  // Add JS that is specific only to current page
  res.locals.custom_java_script.push('/js/departments.js');

  var company_for_template,
    model = req.app.get('db_model');

  req.user.getCompany({
    scope : ['with_active_users', 'order_by_active_users'],
  })
  .then(function(company){
    company_for_template = company;
    return company.getDepartments({
      scope : ['with_simple_users', 'with_boss'],
      order : [[ model.Department.default_order_field() ]],
    });
  })
  .then(function(departments){
    res.render('departments_overview', {
      title             : 'Departments settings',
      departments       : departments,
      allowance_options : generate_all_department_allowances(),
      company           : company_for_template,
    });
  });
});
```

What i don't understand is a single line of code I.E. `req.user.getCompany`. Where is the `getCompany` method being attached to the `user` object. I have a bit of a fuzzy understanding. I'll list out my understanding below.

So basically the user object is being attached by `passport.js` is what i believe, but where and how exactly is the `getCompany` being attached to the user object ?

The only partial clue i have is this answer [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23524426/4381665) I.E. the `deserializeUser`, when i see that i only see the below (code can be found **[HERE](https://github.com/timeoff-management/timeoff-management-application/blob/master/lib/passport/index.js#L161)**, on the repo.) :

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {

    model.User.find({where : {id : id}}).then(function(user){
      return user.reload_with_session_details();
    })
    .then(function(user){
      done(null, user);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.error('Failed to fetch session user '+id+' with error: '+error);

      done(null, false, { message : 'Failed to fetch session user' });
    });
  });
```

And from here on i am a bit lost for clues. Any suggestions on where and how the `getCompany` method is being attached would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `timeoff-management` lib is using `Sequelize` for the `User` model and if you look at here https://github.com/timeoff-management/timeoff-management-application/blob/master/lib/model/db/user.js#L561, the `User` model has an association to `Company` model.

When the association is defined between two models, Sequelize will create a couple of mixins which is available on an instance.

With the `as` option is presented, these mixins will be generated on the `User` instance.  (Some plural forms will be also generated but I couldn't confirm.)

```
userInstance.getCompany()
userInstance.countCompany()
userInstance.hasCompany()
userInstance.setCompany()
userInstance.addCompany()
userInstance.removeCompany()
userInstance.createCompany()
```

For more detail about Sequelize mixins, please check it out here https://sequelize.org/v6/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances.

Comment: thanks alot , you made quick work of something that might hv taken me forever :D