# nodejs + passportjs + mongoose: How to pass provider name to templates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, mongoose-schema

I am use passport js for a user credential management and in mongoose schema document:

```
var customerSchema = new Schema({
    info: {
        firstname: String,
        lastname: String,
        telephone: String,
        fax: String
    },
    local: {
        email: {
            type: String
        },
        password: {
            type: String
        }
    },
        facebook: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String,
        photo: String
    },
    google: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String,
        photo: String
    },
    status: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

When login with passportjs and add provider name:

```
passport.use('local.login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done) {
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email address invalid.').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password invalid.').notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        var messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
    }
    //find user
    Customer.findOne({
        'local.email': email
    }, function(err, customer) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        if (!customer) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Customer not found.'
            });
        }
        if (!customer.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Customer info invalid.'
            });
        }
        customer.provider = "local"; //Add more var to customer info
        console.log("User Info: " + customer.provider);
        return done(null, customer);
    });

}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("Serialize User: " + user);
    done(null, user._id);
});
```

When login by local passport or facebook i want add custom field into passport session return provider info pass to template.

So how can I do this in Passport?

UPDATE 1:

defined var:

```
var provider = null;
```

in:

```
...
if (!customer.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, {
             message: 'Customer info invalid.'
        });
}
provider = "local"; //Add more var to customer info
return done(null, customer);
...
```

I have use @Love-Kesh help code:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(customerId, done) {

    Customer.findById(customerId, function(err, user) {

        var newUser = user.toObject();
        newUser['provider'] = provider;

        done(err, newUser);
    });
});
```

It working for my mean. provider return dynamic value by methods local, facebook...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    passport.use('local.login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, email, password, done) {
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email address invalid.').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password invalid.').notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        var messages = [];
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
            messages.push(error.msg);
        });
        return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
    }


    //check if user local 
    //need to pass provider from client side
    if(req.body.provider=='local'){

        //find user
        Customer.findOne({
            'local.email': email
        }, function(err, customer) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if (!customer) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Customer not found.'
                });
            }
            if (!customer.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Customer info invalid.'
                });
            }
        customer.provider = "local"; //Add more var to customer info
        console.log("User Info: " + customer.provider);
        return done(null, customer);
    });

    }else{

        //do whatever you want

    }
});

}



}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("Serialize User: " + user);

    //pass complete user here 
    done(null, user);
});
```

**Updated below code**

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(loggedUser, done) {
            var provider = loggedUser.provider;

           Customer.findById(loggedUser.id,function(error, user) {

            //need to convert into object
            var newUser=user.toObject();                   
            newUser['provider']=provider;

            return done(null, newUser);



        });

          //or return direct  return done(null, loggedUser);
       });
```

Comment: thankyou @Love-Kesk. My mean add custom var into passport session: req.user.provider and access in my template.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to add extra info on `passport session`.

So, If you want to add custom info on passport session then you can add it in `deserializeUser`

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    getUser(id).then(function(user) {
        user.anything = 'whatever you want';
        return done(null, user);
    });
});
```

You can get one more [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313332/adding-extra-information-in-user-object-in-passport-js-or-somewhere-in-session)

Comment: thankyou. I want check when customer login by `local` or `facebook`, `google` ... method. If add here then static value.

Comment: Simplest way you can give flag value as per your requirement eg, `user.isFacebookUser:true`. same in your all provider, and check later that value where you want

Comment: I try add simple text `user.provider = "mymethod";`  and `console.log(req.user);` in router but info not return provider is mymethod.

Comment: it should  work, debug it when adding the value (is it coming) and check at your targeted place

Comment: above this line `return done(null, user);` check you get proper value