# Using the results of one Mongoose query for another one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building an app in Node and using Mongoose with CosmosDB. I want to display all of the plots owned by the company with which the logged in user is associated.

I have a user, from Passport.js, whose email I use to query the database in order to return his company. That returns fine.

Where I'm having trouble: once I have his company, I want to run a second query to get all the plots which belong to it. This should be bringing back an array of objects, but it returns an empty array.

Two questions:

1. How can I make the current code work?
2. The current structure is very awkward-how do I make it more elegant?

Code:

```
   app.get('/plots',
        requireAuth,
        function(req, res) {
            let company;
            User.find({ email: req.user.email }).lean().exec(function(err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                if (!results) {
                    res.send(null);
                    return;
                } else {
                    company = results[0].company;
                };
            }).then(
                PlotCast.find({ owner: company }).lean().exec(function(err, results) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('error', err);
                        res.send(err);
                    } else if (!results) {
                        res.send(null);
                    } else {
                        console.log('results', results);
                        res.send(results);
                    }
                })
            ).catch(function(e) {
                console.log('error', e);
            });
        }
    )
```

Comment: Use `findOne()`  in your first query. I usually avoid callback hell by using async.js (in your case async.waterfall() would be useful).

Comment: Using findOne returns the same result. The first query was running fine, it's the second one that is the problem.

Comment: Can't you just use the `req.user` object without having to query the collection again? If that doesn't have the `company` field perhaps you can populate it when you serialize user into session with passport.

Comment: Ah-right-in passport.js, I return a user like this: `return done(null, user);`, and that should have a company associated. But it doesn't. How do I add this property?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313332/

Comment: thanks, but this means doing it manually through another database query, and I don't see what I'm gaining here, except that perhaps I'm saving some queries if the user reloads the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never bad to have an alternative solution.

I personally hate working directly with Promises and prefer to use [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). In your case [async.waterfall()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) would be useful, as you basically pass down the result from one async task to the next async task.

```
app.get('/plots', requireAuth, function(req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        function getUser(done) {
            // use findOne, not find -- as you only want to retrive ONE user; using find is more expensive
            User.findOne({ email: req.user.email }).lean().exec(done);
        },
        function getCasts(user, done) {
            PlotCast.find({ owner: user.company }).lean().exec(done);
        },
    ], function (err, casts) {
        // if an error occurs during the above tasks ^, it will come down here
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).send(e);
        }
        // otherwise if all tasks finish, it will come down here
        res.json(casts);
    });
});
```

So the benefit of using async.js is that you can centralize all your errors in one place opposed to having multiple places (which is also fine depending on what you are doing).

I think your initial problem is that you were using callback AND promises together. Usually you use one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Actually to make it more elegant you should use Promises, let say [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) library (or any other preferred)

So when you require mongoose provide it with a Promise library and the code should look better and be more readable and sequential

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

app.get('/plots', requireAuth,
        function(req, res) {
            User.find({ email: req.user.email }).lean()
                .then(function(results) {
                    if (!results) throw new Error('User not found');
                    else return results[0].company;
                })
                .then(function(company) {
                    return PlotCast.find({ owner: company }).lean();
                })
                .then(function(results) {
                    if (!results) throw new Error('Plot Cast not found')
                    else {
                        console.log('results', results);
                        res.send(results);
                    }
                })
                .catch(function(e) {
                    console.log('error', e);
                    res.status(400).send(e);
                });
        })
```

Comment: Two questions:
1) You required Bluebird twice-by mistake?
2) The only reason that I used `let company` was to provide a variable which I could store the return from the user query. In your example, we are querying PlotCast for objects where the owner is the company variable, but we never actually set company to equal anything. Does this somehow happen under the hood in the first query?

Comment: 1) sorry, yes I required it by mistake, will update 2) `company` was returned from the previous `.then()` in `else return results[0].company`

Comment: Right, I understand we `return results[0].company`, but that's just whatever value corresponds to key `company` in the first result. We never set the variable company to equal that return-right?

Comment: Aw, right, we just return it from previous promise and use. You definitely can store the value in `company` if you need it somewhere in the code rather just making request to `PlotCast`

Comment: No, that's great, I would rather do it this way, I just want to know how it knows that when we say `.then(function(company) {
                    return PlotCast.find({ owner: company }).lean();
                })`, the company which we are referring to is the return from the previous statement.

Also-it seems that there is something wrong with the whole PlotCast.find query, since when I hardwire it with PlotCast.find({ owner: "winery" }), I get an empty array in return...

Comment: It knows about `company` value because it's a standard promise mechanism, when I return something from previous `.then` statement it is passed to the next one. I'll remove `let company` to avoid misunderstandings. We can proceed in chat if you want but it seems I lack 20 reputation points to do it :)